# Advent Calendar (Daily) Session Count Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are implementing an Advent Calendar on our Website in a dedicated Landing Page (mywebsite/adventcalendar).

As every day Users can win a prize by clicking on the "box" of the day; I would like to know at the end of the 24-days Campaign, how many days on average users interacted with the Advent calendar.

How can I achieve that using Tag Manager/Analytics?

I was thinking about placing a First Party Cookie with GTM the first time that the user land on the dedicated landing page and then use it in a Custom Segment to filter out the Frequency & Recency report on Google Analytics.

Would that work? Do you have a better idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: I guess my solution it's not accurate because I would not be able to make a distinction between Users that registered more session in a day and 1 session per day?

Comment: Is this an authenticated app? Will you know if a user's "opened" the prize for the day from the app?

Comment: What about creating a virtual page view for every day (e.g. "/advent/day1" )? Then you can create report for unique visitors and filter the pages they visited containing "/advent/" - would that give you information you are looking for?... btw. not a great question for this forum, you should stay more on topic, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: No t's not an authenticated app. By " how many days on average users interacted with the Advent calendar" I rather meant how many days the user land on my landing page. The actual interaction with the calendar is not the focus in the first place...